# there exist infinite many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S_n-[S_n]<\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, conjectures

Let $S_n:=1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1n$. Is it true that the set of $n\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$S_n-[S_n]<\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
is infinite?
Here, $[x]$ represents the largest integer not exceeding $x$.

This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062960/there-exist-infinite-many-n-in-mathbbn-such-that-s-n-s-n-frac1n2?noredirect=1#comment4256200_2062960) without receiving any answers.

Comment: Who is $H_n$? what's its relation to the question? The second part is very vague as it is, even when I try to compare this post to the math.se question. Can you re-edit?

Comment: BTW I should say that I appreciate that you have added link to your post on math.SE. (There are many users who repost question here without mentioning that it has been previously posted on another site.)

Comment: Any background? Any numerical data? I am just curious--the question seems interesting to me as it is. One may ask about the opposite inequality $\ldots\ > -\frac 1{n^2}\ $ as well.

Comment: The heuristic in the post on MSE is natural to use, but you need to be more careful -- I'm pretty sure $H_n$ is not equidistributed mod 1. Indeed, it has the same rate of growth as $\log n$, and growth rate arguments (e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950100/show-that-a-log-n-is-not-equidistributed-for-any-a) suffice to show that $\log n$ is not equidistributed mod 1. The comments in that post might help with this problem.